# Determine type of value of SqlReader field

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, .net-4.5

I am doing something like this:

```
if(dataType == "string")
    list.Add((string)reader[column]);
else if (dataType == "date")
    list.Add(DbToDate(reader, column));
else if (dataType == "double")
    list.Add(DbToDouble(reader, column));
else if (dataType == "int")
    list.Add(DbToInt(reader, column));
```

**dataType is a string being passed into the method.**

I am imagining a simpler solution something like this:

```
if(reader[column].Type == "string)
    list.Add((string)reader[column]);
else if .....
```

Basically the Q is - **How can I ask the reader what Data Type its giving me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reader.GetFieldType(i).FullName or reader.GetDataTypeName(i)` where i is the column index